# Python is using different site packages than pip installed

Tags: python, package

The site packages pip installs are located in:

```
$ python -m site --user-site
/Users/ustroetz/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages
```

The site packages Python is using are here:

```
>>> import site
>>> site.getsitepackages()
['/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages']
```

Where is the ideal place to put the site-packages if I don't use a virtual environment?

How do I change the location of either which site packages python uses or where pip installs them by default?

---

Also I am confused about the correct location of Python

```
$ which python
/usr/bin/python

>>> import sys
>>> sys.prefix
'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7'
```

I am on Mac OS X 10.9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define the location of your user site directory with the [PYTHONUSERBASE](http://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONUSERBASE) environment variable. The location you indicated in your question is the default for a Mac (see [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/site.html#site.USER_SITE)).

If you are not using a virtual environment, I recommend putting the packages somewhere under your user directory to avoid breaking anything at the system level (or having user-code break due to system-level changes).

With regard to the location of Python, try typing

```
ls -lAF /usr/bin/python
```

and you should find that it is actually a symbolic link that points to an executable under your `sys.prefix` directory.

Comment: If I type: `ls -lAF /usr/bin/python`. I get `-rwxr-xr-x  2 root  wheel  58608 Oct 22 14:18 /usr/bin/python*`

Comment: Interesting. I just tried it on a Mac and got the result I described. I will try on another system (with more recent OS X) and see if I get the same result as you.

Answer (score 1):

In macosx It should be:
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7

which includes the Python executable and libraries

Comment: Okay, that's were it is. But pip installs them somewhere else. Is that normal? How do I change that?